# Best way to create array of ten 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking an alternatives to the following, I'm pretty new in javascritpt:

```
var values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: alternative to what? what are you trying to achieve? how do you create this array? why you think your method is not good enough?

Comment: `Array(10).fill(0)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop:

```
var res = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   res.push(0);
}
```

or this:

```
var res = Array(10).fill(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) :

```
const array = Array(10).fill(0)
```

or [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) :

```
const array = Array.from(Array(10), a => 0);
```